# error Missing return type on function in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have this function, but when compiling the app.

```
public async test(options?: { engine?: Config }): Promise<any> {
        const hostel = new Service({
            list: this.servicesList,
            createService: list => this.dbService.buildService(list)
        });
     return hostel.load();
    }
```

I have this error:

```
26:27  error  Missing return type on function                             
@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type.
```

on this line `createService: list => this.dbService.buildService(list) text**`

Comment: Basically you have one function which doesn't have return type on 26th row

Comment: The error described  is that you have declared a return type of `Promise<any>` but are not returning anything from your `test` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only should add return in the function

```
public async test(options?: { engine?: Config }): Promise<any> {
   const hostel = new Service({
      list: this.servicesList,
      createService: list => this.dbService.buildService(list)
   });
   return hostel;// Missing line
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Andrew in the comments, you are not returning anything from the function. If that's what you expect, just change `Promise<any>` to `Promise<void>`